# Need to write two query one for insert the record and other for update the record in main table

Tags: mysql

I need to write two separate query one for insert the record in main table and other one for update the record in same main table.

Condition : I need to insert and update the main table from other table which is exactly same in structure as main table.Below are rules for doing the same

1: We need to match three condition from both the table like provider_id,NPI AND TAX .If we found match in both the table then it will update the same record in main table from other table.

2:If any of above three check doesnt match then it will insert the full record in main table from other table.

Note : We need not to use the not exists condition for doing the same.It will be good if we use outer join for doing the same.

Please find my code which is inserting the duplicate record each time which it should not..

```
INSERT INTO inc.prov_stext_ma_archive (SEQ_ID,SOURCE_ID,SOURCE_TYPE,SUBMITTER_PLAN_ID,PROVIDER_ID,ID_TYPE,STATE_LICENSE_NUMBER,MEDICAID_NUMBER,FULL_NAME,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,OFFICE_ADDRESS_STREET,OFFICE_ADDRESS_CITY,OFFICE_ADDRESS_STATE,OFFICE_ADDRESS_ZIP,MAILING_ADDRESS_STREET,MAILING_ADDRESS_CITY,MAILING_ADDRESS_STATE,MAILING_ADDRESS_ZIP,PROVIDER_TYPE,FILLER,EFFECTIVE_DATE,TERM_DATE,NON_PAR_INDICATOR,NETWORK_ID,IPA_PMG_ID,PANEL_OPEN_INDICATOR,PROVIDER_DEA_NUMBER,PROVIDER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,MEDICARE_ID,SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER,NAPB_NUMBER,TAX_ID,IPA_PMG_ID_TYPE,GENDER_CODE,PRIMARY_CARE_ELIG_IND,STATE_SPECIALTY,STATE_SPECIALTY_DESCRIPTION,MCE_PROV_TYPE,MCE_PROV_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,VEND_SPECIALTY,COS_UR_IND,COS_CREDENTIALS,COS_PANEL_NBR,COS_PROV_IDENT,TAXONOMY_CODE,CONTRACT_TYPE,STATUS,ERROR_ID,ERROR_DESCRIPTION,USER_DEF_1,USER_DEF_2,USER_DEF_3,USER_DEF_4,USER_DEF_5,
INSERT_DATETIME,INSERT_PROCESS,INSERT_USER,UPDATE_DATETIME,UPDATE_PROCESS,UPDATE_USER,TYPE_SPEC_STATUS) 
SELECT  W.SEQ_ID, W.SOURCE_ID, W.SOURCE_TYPE, W.SUBMITTER_PLAN_ID, W.PROVIDER_ID, W.ID_TYPE, W.STATE_LICENSE_NUMBER, W.MEDICAID_NUMBER, W.FULL_NAME, W.LAST_NAME, W.FIRST_NAME, W.OFFICE_ADDRESS_STREET, W.OFFICE_ADDRESS_CITY, W.OFFICE_ADDRESS_STATE, W.OFFICE_ADDRESS_ZIP, W.MAILING_ADDRESS_STREET, W.MAILING_ADDRESS_CITY, W.MAILING_ADDRESS_STATE, W.MAILING_ADDRESS_ZIP, W.PROVIDER_TYPE, W.FILLER, W.EFFECTIVE_DATE, W.TERM_DATE, W.NON_PAR_INDICATOR, W.NETWORK_ID, W.IPA_PMG_ID, W.PANEL_OPEN_INDICATOR, W.PROVIDER_DEA_NUMBER, W.PROVIDER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, W.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER, W.MEDICARE_ID, W.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER, W.NAPB_NUMBER, W.TAX_ID, W.IPA_PMG_ID_TYPE, W.GENDER_CODE, W.PRIMARY_CARE_ELIG_IND, W.STATE_SPECIALTY, W.STATE_SPECIALTY_DESCRIPTION, W.MCE_PROV_TYPE, W.MCE_PROV_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, W.VEND_SPECIALTY, W.COS_UR_IND, W.COS_CREDENTIALS, W.COS_PANEL_NBR, W.COS_PROV_IDENT, W.TAXONOMY_CODE, W.CONTRACT_TYPE, W.STATUS, W.ERROR_ID, W.ERROR_DESCRIPTION, W.USER_DEF_1, W.USER_DEF_2, W.USER_DEF_3, W.USER_DEF_4, W.USER_DEF_5,
A.INSERT_DATETIME, W.INSERT_PROCESS, W.INSERT_USER, W.UPDATE_DATETIME, W.UPDATE_PROCESS, W.UPDATE_USER, W.TYPE_SPEC_STATUS
FROM INC.MA_PROV_ST_EX_FULL W LEFT OUTER JOIN  inc.prov_stext_ma_archive A ON( A.provider_id = W.provider_id
AND A.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER = W.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER
AND A.TAXONOMY_CODE = W.TAXONOMY_CODE AND A.PROVIDER_ID IS NULL)
WHERE  W.SOURCE_ID = 'COSMOS'
```

Comment: Sorry Eric , i am not asking to write code i am just going to provide the sample of code which i have written So far.

Comment: Ok there wasn't any sample when I checked your post, post upvoted.

Comment: Can you please check now and help me out to resolve this..